# Is there any basis for the Kirk/Uhura flirting?

Tags: star-trek, canon, star-trek-tos, romantic-interest

Other than in the [Mirror Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_Universe_%28Star_Trek%29), is there any basis in prior Star Trek canon for the existence - however one-sided or not - of any "love interest" between Kirk and Uhura?

I'm asking with curiosity about whether Orci and Kurtzman made this up for J.J.'s STAR TREK, or if they possibly drew it from somewhere in canon.

Please note, I also am looking for actual interest on either Kirk or Uhura's part. Not just when under the influence of or "playing along with" any alien or its plans. For example, this excludes their famous "first inter-racial kiss" moment. In the plot, that was forced on them by alien influence, not enacted by them under their free-will.

Essentially I am looking for any evidence of **genuine** feelings or interest on either of their parts.

Comment: you mean besides the fact Kirk was attracted to basically any female humanoid?

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to "sci-fi-sexual-fantasy" forum.

Comment: LOL - yes, besides that fact. Was there ever anything specifically developed between the two of them that may have informed Orci and Kurtzman, or was that just part of their re-imagined timeline.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No.**

If Kirk wanted to pounce on Uhura presumably he would have done so under the influence of the "polywater" in "The Naked Time."  Kirk had another chance in "The Enemy Within" when the transporter separated him into Good Kirk and Bad Kirk.  Good Kirk had no libido at all.  Bad Kirk attacked Janice Rand, not Uhura, and was rebuffed.  Kirk had a chance to conjure up a willing Uhura in "Shore Leave", but an old girlfriend and an old bully were all he could manage.

Uhura expressed admiration for Kirk's command ability in "Plato's Stepchildren" and *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*, and was visibly distraught when she thought Kirk had died in "Space Seed".  However, no romantic yearnings were evident.  When Uhura's fantasies were probed in "The Man Trap" the salt-sucking creature manifested as a handsome black man, not as Kirk.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been difficult to show any sort of willing, flirtatious behaviour at the time, given network sensibilities. There was certainly respect between the two, and even friendship (Uhura's reaction to Kirk's apparent death in The Tholian Web certainly goes beyond what one would expect at the thought of losing a commanding officer).

Comment: Can you provide any basis for that first sentence ?

Comment: @Stan: The involuntary Kirk/Uhura kiss in "Plato's Stepchildren" was extremely controversial at the time, especially in the South. Interracial marriage was illegal in some US states until 1967; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loving_v_virginia.

Comment: @KeithThompson was suggesting to Derek that he needed to provide some support in his answer for his statement. Am a child of the 60's so I do understand :)

Comment: It's funny how anti-miscegenation attitudes work. Kirk can hook up with any alien species across the galaxy without audiences batting an eye, and even non-humanoid species from beyond the Milky Way or alien robots, so long as they're "white" alien robots. But as soon as he kisses a black human female, there's a controversy all of a sudden.